# How do I recover a semaphore when the process that decremented it to zero crashes?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, semaphore

I have multiple apps compiled with g++, running in Ubuntu.  I'm using named semaphores to co-ordinate between different processes.

All works fine *except* in the following situation:  If one of the processes calls `sem_wait()` or `sem_timedwait()` to decrement the semaphore and then crashes or is killed -9 before it gets a chance to call `sem_post()`, then from that moment on, the named semaphore is "unusable".

By "unusable", what I mean is the semaphore count is now zero, and the process that should have incremented it back to 1 has died or been killed.

I cannot find a `sem_*()` API that might tell me the process that last decremented it has crashed.

Am I missing an API somewhere?

Here is how I open the named semaphore:

```
sem_t *sem = sem_open( "/testing",
    O_CREAT     |   // create the semaphore if it does not already exist
    O_CLOEXEC   ,   // close on execute
    S_IRWXU     |   // permissions:  user
    S_IRWXG     |   // permissions:  group
    S_IRWXO     ,   // permissions:  other
    1           );  // initial value of the semaphore
```

Here is how I decrement it:

```
struct timespec timeout = { 0, 0 };
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout );
timeout.tv_sec += 5;

if ( sem_timedwait( sem, &timeout ) )
{
    throw "timeout while waiting for semaphore";
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Turns out there isn't a way to reliably recover the semaphore.  Sure, anyone can `post_sem()` to the named semaphore to get the count to increase past zero again, but how to tell when such a recovery is needed?  The API provided is too limited and doesn't indicate in any way when this has happened.

Beware of the ipc tools also available -- the common tools `ipcmk`, `ipcrm`, and `ipcs` are only for the outdated SysV semaphores.  They specifically do not work with the new POSIX semaphores.

But it looks like there are other things that can be used to lock things, which the operating system does automatically release when an application dies in a way that cannot be caught in a signal handler.  Two examples:  a listening socket bound to a particular port, or a lock on a specific file.

I decided the lock on a file is the solution I needed.  So instead of a `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` call, I'm using:

```
lockf( fd, F_LOCK, 0 )
```

and

```
lockf( fd, F_ULOCK, 0 )
```

When the application exits in any way, the file is automatically closed which also releases the file lock.  Other client apps waiting for the "semaphore" are then free to proceed as expected.

Thanks for the help, guys.

---

UPDATE:

12 years later, thought I should point out that posix mutexes do have a "robust" attribute.  That way, if the owner of the mutex gets killed or exits, the next user to lock the mutex will get the non-error return value of `EOWNERDEAD`, allowing the mutex to be recovered.  This will make it similar to the file and socket locking solution.  Look up `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust()` and `pthread_mutex_consistent()` for details.  Thanks, Reinier Torenbeek, for this hint.

Comment: +1, in ended up doing the same thing, semaphores are useless in such scenarios

Comment: Someone e-mailed me to ask for more details. I did write a small blog post almost 3 years ago when I ran into this problem. More details on how I solved it with file lock is available here: http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2010-01-13_PosixSemaphores/index.html

Comment: Can the same thing be achieved by simply opening a closing a file? I found this on the man page for open(): "When opening a file, a lock with flock(2) semantics can be obtained by setting O_SHLOCK for a shared lock, or O_EXLOCK for an exclusive lock."

Comment: Hi, Any hint on replacing sem_timedwait? Does 'select' block/unblock on locks?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal Agreed. Funny enough, I had a look at the sqlite code base and they are using POSIX semaphores!

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this when I want my semaphore to have a higher initial value? I could have a list of files, and iterate through them finding one to lock, but that would rapidly get expensive...

Comment: @Stéphane Maybe also consider using mutex by sharing memory?? I just found this post here: [Is it possible to use mutex in multiprocessing case on Linux/UNIX ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389730/is-it-possible-to-use-mutex-in-multiprocessing-case-on-linux-unix)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with flock is queueing is not fair at all. With 3 tasks or more number of turns waited can be anything ... mutex / semaphore don't make guarantees either but in practice you get 99% fifo order.

Comment: Argh. 2022 and I am still stumbling across this problem.
The fact that the POSIX Semaphores don't offer a way to handle crash reliable is... bad.
The fact that the "outdated SysV semaphores" DO offer this is even worse. And MacOS doesn't even have a "sem_timedwait"; which makes the oh so modern POSIX Semaphores completely useless. What a sad state of affairs.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.3.html says, "The robustness attribute specifies the behavior of the mutex when the owning thread dies without unlocking the mutex."

Does this apply to different processes using the same mutex in, say, shared memory?

Answer (score 6):

Use a lock file instead of a semaphore, much like @Stéphane's solution but without the flock() calls. You can simply open the file using an exclusive lock:

```
//call to open() will block until it can obtain an exclusive lock on the file.
errno = 0;
int fd = open("/tmp/.lockfile", 
    O_CREAT | //create the file if it's not present.
    O_WRONLY | //only need write access for the internal locking semantics.
    O_EXLOCK, //use an exclusive lock when opening the file.
    S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); //permissions on the file, 600 here.

if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("Entered critical section.\n");
//Do "critical" stuff here.
//...

//exit the critical section
errno = 0;
if (close(fd) == -1) {
    perror("close() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("Exited critical section.\n");
```

Comment: Good code, with 1 modification:  You should create the lock file before contention begins, and, of course, keep it linked.  Otherwise, in my tests in Mac OS X 10.10 DP5, open() can succeed for two peer processes contending to initially create the file, if within a few milliseconds.  Issue occurs with either Stéphane's or Raffi's code.

I then stress-tested.  Result: Raffi's code worked perfectly, Stéphane's code not quite.  I did not study why.  If interested see https://github.com/jerrykrinock/ClassesObjC/blob/master/SSYSemaphore.h, and .m.

Comment: @JerryKrinock But, doesn't `open()` create the lock file if it's not present (when given the O_CREAT) flag?

Comment: I'm going to shoot from the hip, because I don't have the 30 minutes that it would take to properly refresh my understanding of this available right now.  I think the answer is that, yes, open() with O_CREAT will create the file if needed, but if two processes execute open() within a few milliseconds of each other, results are unpredictable.  Hence my suggestion to create the lock file before it matters; well, I'll add, unless it is OK for the first contention to be a throwaway.

Comment: compiling error："error: ‘O_EXLOCK’ undeclared (first use in this function)", Ubuntu16.04 LTS

Answer (score 5):

This is a typical problem when managing semaphores.  Some programs use a single process to manage the initialization/deletion of the semaphore.  Usually this process does just this and nothing else.  Your other applications can wait until the semaphore is available.  I've seen this done with the SYSV type API, but not with POSIX.  Similar to what '**Duck**' mentioned, using the SEM_UNDO flag in your semop() call.

**But,** with the information that you've provided I would suggest that you do not to use semaphores.  Especially if your process is in danger of being killed or crashing.  Try to use something that the OS will cleanup automagically for you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to double check but I believe sem_post can be called from a signal handler.  If you are able to catch some of the situations that are bringing down the process this might help.

Unlike a mutex any process or thread (with permissions) can post to the semaphore.  You can write a simple utility to reset it.  Presumably you know when your system has deadlocked.  You can bring it down and run the utility program.

Also the semaphone is usually listed under /dev/shm and you can remove it.

SysV semaphores are more accommodating for this scenario.  You can specify SEM_UNDO, in which the system will back out changes to the semaphore made by a process if it dies.  They also have the ability to tell you the last process id to alter the semaphore.

Comment: Some signals like kill -9 bypasses signal handers, which is the situation I've run into.  I do have a signal handler for the ones I can catch, and in a destructor for a scope-based object I do call sem_post() as the stack unwinds.  But those few lingering uncatchable signals is what I was hoping to solve.

Comment: I think a fair question is to ask who are the users and why are they killing the app that way?  You can try the SysV route or even file locks, which should revert when the process dies.

Comment: Actually, that is what I decided to do last night.  Since files that have been open() and lockf() are automatically released when applications are killed -9, this method of "communication" actually works more reliably than semaphores considering what I need to coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find it from the shell using `lsof`. Then possibly you can delete it?

**Update**

Ah yes... `man -k semaphore` to the rescue.

It seems you can use `ipcrm` to get rid of a semaphore. Seems you aren't the first with this problem.

Comment: Yes, I know about ipcrm, but it doesn't help.  If I knew the semaphore had been lost, I could just as easily sem_post() to "get it back".  The problem seems to be there is no event triggered to indicate that the application that last decremented it has been killed.

Comment: In addition, just noticed on the man page that ipcrm only works on the old SysV semaphores, not POSIX semaphores.  Same with ipcs.

Answer (score 1):

If the process was KILLed then there won't be any direct way to determine that it has gone away.

You could operate some kind of periodic integrity check across all the semaphores you have - use [semctl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semctl) (cmd=GETPID) to find the PID for the last process that touched each semaphore in the state you describe, then check whether that process is still around.  If not, perform clean up.

Comment: Something along these lines is what I was looking for, but of course for the POSIX semaphores you'd find in #include <semaphore.h>.  From what I can tell, the semctl() style of calls are specific to the old SysV semaphores from <sys/sem.h>.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a named semaphore, then you can use an algorithm like the one used in `lsof` or `fuser`.

Take these in your consideration:

1.Each named POSIX semaphore creates a file in a tmpfs file system usually under the path:

```
/dev/shm/
```

2.Each process has a map_files in linux, under the path:

```
/proc/[PID]/map_files/
```

These map files, shows which part of a process memory map to what!

So using these steps, you can find whether the named semaphore is still opened by another process or not:

1- (Optional) Find the exact path of named semaphore (In case its not under `/dev/shm`)

- First open the named semaphore in the new process and assign the result to a pointer
- Find the address location of the pointer in the memory (usually with a casting of the address of the pointer to in integer type) and convert it to hexadecimal (i.e result: `0xffff1234`) number and then use this path:

  `/proc/self/map_files/ffff1234-*`

  there should be only one file that fulfills this criteria.
- Get the symbolic link target of that file. It is the full path of the named semaphore.

2- Iterate over all processes to find a map file that its symbolic link taget matches the full path of the named semaphore. If there is one, then the semaphore is in real use, but if there is none, then you can safely unlink the named semaphore and reopen it again for your usage.

**UPDATE**

In step 2, when iterating over all processes, instead of iterating over all files in the folder `map_file`, it is beter to use the file `/proc/[PID]/maps` and search the full path of the named semaphore file (i.e: `/dev/shm/sem_xyz`) inside it.
In this approach, even if some other programs unlinked the named semaphore but the semaphore is still using in other processes, it still can be found but a flag of "(deleted)" is appended at the end of its file path.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do a `sem_unlink()` immediately after the `sem_open()`.  Linux will remove after all processes have closed the resource, which includes internal closes.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the named semaphore to be deleted?  I didn't want to delete it, I wanted to post it when one of the apps crashed or was killed.  (Multiple apps in use here, all working with the same set of named semaphores to coordinate some internal work.)

Comment: This won't work: if another process is blocked on the semaphore, and the process that has it locked crashes, then the blocked process will keep the semaphore open and so the semaphore will never be destroyed.