# why POSIX doesn't provide a robust IPC semaphore(regarding process crash safety)

Tags: linux, posix, ipc, mutex, semaphore

According to this link,  [How do I recover a semaphore when the process that decremented it to zero crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053679/how-do-i-recover-a-semaphore-when-the-process-that-decremented-it-to-zero-crashe/2058642#2058642) it seems that there is no robust semaphore inter-process, and the author finally chose filelock, which is guaranteed to be released properly by the system-level or kernel-level control.

But I also found robust mutex provided by pthread https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.3.html why there is no something like robust semaphore?

And an extra question: what robust alternatives we have regarding IPC synchronization? filelock seems to be the best one. I think providing such mechanism is not that difficult from system or kernel level,since they do implement fielock. then why they don't provide some other approaches?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a mutex, it can be acquired by at most one thread at a time.  Therefore, once the mutex has been acquired, the owner can write its process ID or thread ID (depending on the system) into the mutex, and future users can detect whether the owner is still alive or not.

However, a semaphore is ultimately a counter.  It is possible that different threads may increment or decrement the counter.  There isn't intrinsically one resource that is being shared; there could instead be multiple resources.

For example, if we're trying to limit ourselves to a certain number of outgoing connections (say, 8), then we could create a semaphore with that value and allow threads to acquire it (wait) to make a connection, and then increment it (post) when they're done.  If we never want to make more than 8 connections at once, the semaphore will never block; we'll have acquired it successfully each time, even though there's no exclusion.

In such a situation, there isn't going to be space inside the semaphore to store every process's thread ID.  Using memory allocation is tricky because that code needs to be synchronized independently, and even if that could be solved, it means that a semaphore value would have at least O(N) performance when acquiring the semaphore.  I work on a production system that uses hundreds of threads, so you can imagine the performance problems if we had such a semaphore design.

There are other solutions which you can use when you need robustness, such as file locking or a robust mutex in a shared memory segment, but none of them have the same properties as a semaphore.  Therefore, any discussion of what primitives should be used instead depends on the particular needs of the situation (which should probably be placed in a new question).